# How to make a TWinControl display only and let its parent handle all mouse events?

Tags: delphi

I am creating a user component, adding some extra labels on a button (using code) but when clicking over the labels, the buttons' onClick event do not fire.

It is troublesome and not effective to create all mouse related events for those labels and point them back to the button's events.

Are there more simple ways to let the button to handle all those mouse events just like those labels are not there?

The actual situation is much more complex and the label is TJvLinkLabel for simple markup rendering so simply drawing text on the button is not a good options for my case.

Thanks for your kind help.

Edit :
To be more specific.  There are an array of buttons, each display info of a table records.  Each of them has 2 TJvLinkLabel as Header and Footer which has Simple Marked up caption to display various fields info and 1 TJvLabel (alClient, shadow, wordwrap) to display main description.  Each buttons can be in different color or even has background picture and that's why the shadow is needed to bring the text out.  The button's own caption is always set to empty.

I actually only need the visual effect (markup rendering, shadow) and do not need any interaction of those labels.  I just want the button to act as if there is no other components hosted.

When I searched the stackoverflow, I see that C# seems to set the hittest to false or the like but I can't find a similar setting in Delphi.

Edit2 :
More simply put, is there a way to let the parent (button in this case) handle all the mouse messages and do not pass to its children (labels in this case).  Thanks.

Edit 3 :
I had by far inherited labels classes and route the Click, DblClick, MouseDown, MouseUp procedure to the button and skipped other events at the moment.  I would like to know if there is better solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using hyperlinks on these labels? Who do you want to handle those, the button or the label. Any chance of a screen shot to help us visualise?

Comment: if you can't assign OnClick of labels.. may be you can create TJvLinkLabel descendant class, override `Click` to `parent.click`, and use it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan They are not using hyperlink and I only want the visual effects of the labels to replace the original single plain caption.

Comment: @teran This method I had thought with.  This can be done with mousedown, mouseup, click, dblClick but how about mouseenter and mouseleave?  It seems not good to trigger mouseleave of the button and then trigger mouseenter again (by the label routing).

Comment: You will find an interesting answer to your question here -> [Transfer mousedown event on a control to its parent control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74054894/1972425)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't derive from TWinControl, or if that is not possible handle all mouse events and pass them to the parent. You may look below for some links:

[Handling mouse events](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/01/handling-mouse-events-in-smart-mobile.html)

You may look at the code of TWinControl:

```
TWinControl = class(TControl)
protected
  property DefWndProc: Pointer read FDefWndProc write FDefWndProc;
  procedure MainWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
public
  procedure DefaultHandler(var Message); override;
```

and override either DefWndProc if your control is not a descendant, or MainWndProc if it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  My Button Component descend from existing button class which definitely is TWinControl descendant.  The same go for the two label controls.  How to override MainWndProc when it is not a virtual method?  And how to pass the Message to the parent?  Frankly, I am not familiar with the Message system.

Comment: You may access the DefWndProc property (if you're a child). Look it up in the source code of TWinControl, and change that property to a pointer to your function.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `Enabled` property of the labels to `False`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Your suggestion work well on TJvLinkLabel.  Great!  However, the TJvLabel become grey and still do not response to onMouseDown (which trigger the pressed effect).  I orignally think that there will be an universal method to skipping the processing of mouse events so I didn't mention the TjvLabel.  Sorry.