# Transfer mousedown event on a control to its parent control

Tags: delphi

There is a label on a panel. Is it possible to transfer mousedown event to parent control, when there is mousedown event on label, it can trigger mousedown event of its parent panel?

Comment: It is possible. But this will need elaboration to get a proper help. Is that label part of your component (thinking of subclassing) ? Why do you need this ?

Comment: Seems you don't care. Never mind...

Comment: @TLama - I think his question is valid and some people provided nice answers, for the question, as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
type
  TMyControl = class(TControl);

procedure TForm1.Label1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
    TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  TMyControl(Label1.Parent).MouseDown(Button, Shift, X, Y);
end;
```

The TMyControl declaration is there to get access to TControl's protected-visibility MouseDown method.

Comment: Don't forget to adjust X,Y.  They should be relative to the control being called, eg: `TMyControl(Label1.Parent).MouseDown(Button, Shift, Label1.Left+X, Label1.Top+Y);`

Answer (score 0):

OnMouseActivate form event help you.
Or you can handle messages WM_MOUSEACTIVATE and CM_MOUSEACTIVATE

Comment: Nope. That's not a good way. In help you can read that [`OnMouseActivate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnMouseActivate): *"Occurs when the user presses a mouse button with the mouse pointer over a control* ***and the parent form is not active."***

Comment: Delphi 2010 in simple application with two form it's work. FormActive comes after OnMouseActivate. Maybe in MDI it's not work can't test now

Comment: @Vasek - So you suggest to use an additional form?

Comment: No! It for test form active

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in "hacking" your TLabel.

-> Redeclare it, and re-implement its `procedure CMHitTest(var Message: TCMHitTest); message CM_HITTEST` as following:

```
procedure TLabel.CMHitTest(var Message: TCMHitTest);
begin
    Message.Result := HTNOWHERE;
end;
```

Doing this, for your `TPanel`, parent of your `TLabel`, the VCL.Controls `function TWinControl.ControlAtPos(xxx): TControl` will return `nil`

Answer (score 0):

WM_PARENTNOTIFY https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms632638(v=vs.85)

Sent to the parent of a child window when the child window is created or destroyed, or when the user clicks a mouse button while the cursor is over the child window. When the child window is being created, the system sends WM_PARENTNOTIFY just before the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function that creates the window returns. When the child window is being destroyed, the system sends the message before any processing to destroy the window takes place.